# How to disconnect bluetooth immediately after a disconnect

Tags: bluetooth, timeout

I have a PS4 Controller that I'm using to control a robot. When the controller dies, the last command the controller sends persists and continues to move the robot in that direction for about 30 seconds. During that time, it says its still connected in the Bluetooth GUI.

I looked for variables in /etc/bluetooth that could have an effect on this but the entirety of the .conf files in there are commented out.

Is there a way for me to get the computer to immediately disconnect the bluetooth connection to the controller once it switches off?

Comment: The robot is not just following the last command given?

Comment: @David the robot is doing the last command. But if the last command is to move forward and the controller disconnects, there is no way to stop it unless I kill the power